# Asterisk MySQL CDR logs only ANSWERED calls

Tags: asterisk, voip

I've been able to setup Asterisk to log CDRs to a MySQL database using the ODBC option. The challenge I am currently facing is that only calls with the disposition ANSWERED are logged. NO ANSWER, BUSY and other calls are not logged in the database though I see the status from the logs.

I place the calls using ARI which connects to a stasis app when the call is answered.

How do I ensure asterisk logs all calls to the database, irrespective of the call status.

I am using Asterisk 16.2.1 and added a additional field to the cdr table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure it in your cdr.conf file please check what content inside. ad d following line in it

```
unanswered = yes
congestion = yes
```

Comment: I just put two field but there huge different configurations on this file which you may set as per your requirements.